# Rewriting URL path in nginx without redirecting

Tags: nginx

For legacy reasons, I have URLs like `https://host.example.com/foo.cgi?id=nnn`. I want `/foo.cgi?id=nnn` to respond with the contents of a file `nnn.html`, where `nnn` is a number that varies.

In nginx, how do I define a custom mapping from URL paths to different file paths without generating redirects? (That is, while I want the contents of `nnn.html` to be served, I want the browser-visible URL to continue to be `foo.cgi?id=nnn`.)

Comment: Do you mean `/foo.cgi?id=nnn.html` or `/foo.cgi?id=nnn`?

Comment: Oops. I meant `/foo.cgi?id=nnn`. Edited question accordingly. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the URI `/foo.cgi` is defunct, you can use an exact match `location` block to process the `id` argument using a `try_files` statement.

For example:

```
location = /foo.cgi {
    root /path/to/files;
    try_files /$arg_id.html =404;
}
```

The URI `/foo.cgi?id=123` will cause Nginx to search for a file at `/path/to/files/123.html` or return a 404 status if not found.